# Изменение размеров иконок в ListView

Tags: delphi-7, delphi, delphi-xe5, delphi-xe2, delphi-xe

Загрузил в ListView иконки. Хочу при нажатии на кнопку изменить их размер. Размер изменяется, но иконки не отображаются, отображаются только подписи к ним. Решил проблему следующим образом: при нажатии на кнопку меняю размеры отображаемых иконок, чищу ListView, загружаю те же иконки. Данный метод работает, но, на мой взгляд, он неоптимален. Есть ли какие-нибудь предположения более оптимального решения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Иконки нужно загружать в `ImageList`, его можно связать в дизайнере форм с `ListView`. Там есть для этого специальное поле или даже несколько. Для элементов `ListView` нужно будет только указать индекс иконки в этом листе, `IconIndex` вроде. Если вам нужно менять иконки, сделайте 2 списка с иконками `ImageList` разных размеров. Если порядок иконок будет совпадать, то вам для изменения размера нужно будет только сменить у `ListView` ассоциацию со списком иконок.

Comment: Круто! Спасибо большое! Я как-то об этом и не подумал)